# Dense_Rank ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by, gaps-and-islands

I've read a few variations of this question, but the solutions don't seem to be working.

I wish to dynamically create a "Subgroup" for each "OrderNo" & "GroupID". Subgroups should be ordered by "OrderLine" eg: (Expected outcome)

```
OrderNo OrderLine   GroupID Subgroup
------------------------------------
10463   1            798    1
10463   2            799    2
10463   3            797    3
10463   5            65     4
10463   6            65     4
10463   7            65     4
10481   4            917    1
10481   5            918    2
10481   6            131    3
10481   7            131    3
10481   8            131    3
10481   9            130    4
```

I've used Dense_Rank() to create the correct groups below but the ordering(and rank) is totally incorrect.

```
SELECT 
    OrderNo, OrderLine, GroupID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY GroupID) AS Subgroup
FROM 
    #temptable
ORDER BY
    OrderNo, OrderLine;
```

Output:

```
OrderNo OrderLine   GroupID Subgroup
------------------------------------
10463   1            798    3
10463   2            799    4
10463   3            797    2
10463   5            65     1
10463   6            65     1
10463   7            65     1
10481   4            917    3
10481   5            918    4
10481   6            131    2
10481   7            131    2
10481   8            131    2
10481   9            130    1
```

Query:

```
-- Temp tables
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(  
    OrderNo varchar(5),  
    OrderLine int, 
    GroupID int
); 

INSERT INTO #temptable (OrderNo, OrderLine, GroupID)
VALUES ('10463', '1', '798'), ('10463', '2', '799'),
       ('10463', '3', '797'), ('10463', '5', '65'),
       ('10463', '6', '65'), ('10463', '7', '65'),
       ('10481', '4', '917'), ('10481', '5', '918'),
       ('10481', '6', '131'), ('10481', '7', '131'),
       ('10481', '8', '131'), ('10481', '9', '130');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to order the `DENSE_RANK` partition by the `OrderLine`, but in cases where more than one record has the same `GroupID`, you want the rank to be the same.  One option is to use a subquery to identify assign a single value for the `OrderLine` (say the minimum) for a set of records which have the same `GroupID`.  This table can then be joined back to your `#temptable`, and the effective `OrderLine` can be used to `DENSE_RANK` as you want.

```
SELECT t1.OrderNo,
       t1.OrderLine,
       t1.GroupID,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.OrderNo ORDER BY t2.OrderLine) AS Subgroup
FROM #temptable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT OrderNo,
           MIN(OrderLine) AS OrderLine,
           GroupID
    FROM #temptable
    GROUP BY OrderNo,
             GroupID
) t2
    ON t1.OrderNo = t2.OrderNo AND
       t1.GroupID = t2.GroupID
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `GroupID` are not always in sequence. The _Subgroups should be ordered by "OrderLine"_ but of course this is skewing the result

Comment: Very clever solution using `MIN(OrderLine)`, my joins (using multiple values) were growing the dataset exponentially and I didnt pursue this avenue. 

Thank you!