# SQL Select MIN in Subquery returns multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a Table with Orders

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| ID | OrderNumber | CartId |
+----+-------------+--------+
|1   | ABDE45677   | 1      |
|2   | ABFRTG456   | 2      |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

One with cart items for each cart (which belongs to an order)

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| ID | CartId | ProductId |
+----+--------+-----------+
|1   | 1      | 34577     |
|2   | 1      | 26846     |
|3   | 2      | 59055     |
|4   | 3      | 43567     |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

And one with cart item events (such as 'sent', 'shipped', 'returned', etc)

```
+----+---------------------+------------+------+
| ID | EventDate           | CartItemId | Type |
+----+---------------------+------------+------+
|1   | 2016-07-12 11:54:12 | 1          |1     |
|2   | 2016-07-12 12:01:12 | 1          |3     |
|3   | 2016-07-12 10:10:00 | 2          |1     |
|4   | 2016-07-12 11:00:00 | 2          |2     |
|5   | 2016-07-13 13:00:00 | 2          |4     |
|6   | 2016-07-12 12:00:00 | 3          |1     |
|7   | 2016-07-14 12:30:12 | 3          |2     |
+----+---------------------+------------+------|
```

The relationships are

```
Orders >hasmany> Carts >hasmany> CartItems >hasmany> CartItemEvents
```

I now want to get all Orders with a 'status' column at the end. This column should display the lowest 'type' value of all cart item events belonging to the order. I only want to get the latest event for each order Item.

```
SELECT o.ID, 
       o.OrderNumber,
       (SELECT MIN(type) FROM CartItemEvents cie WHERE cie.CartItemId=ci.Id 
                                        AND   cie.EventDate=
                                        (SELECT MAX(EventDate) FROM CartItemEvents WHERE ci.id=CartItemId)) 
       AS 'status'
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN CartItems ci on o.CartId=ci.CartId
```

Unfortunately, I get multiple types for each order (one type for each item)

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| ID | OrderNumber | Status |
+----+-------------+--------+
|1   | ABDE45677   | 3      |
|1   | ABDE45677   | 4      |
|2   | ABFRTG456   | 2      |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

It seems like the function

```
SELECT MIN(type)
```

has no effect here, since removing MIN() brings the same result.

How can I get only the minimum type for each order?
Maybe I have too many nested subqueries here?

Comment: I don't think you should left join/subquery this in the select, but you should join all the way through orders, cartitems and cartitem events - because your subquery will not filter your statement.

Comment: I'd look at an inner join with a min() and join the table to it similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382566/dense-rank-ordering/39382601#39382601). I'm on mobile so can't provide an answer but you may see the similarities

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.ID, 
       o.OrderNumber,
       MIN(SELECT MIN(type) FROM CartItemEvents cie WHERE cie.CartItemId=ci.Id 
                                        AND   cie.EventDate=
                                        (SELECT MAX(EventDate) FROM CartItemEvents WHERE ci.id=CartItemId)) 
       AS 'status'
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN CartItems ci on o.CartId=ci.CartId
GROUP BY o.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.ID, 
   o.OrderNumber,
   (SELECT MIN(type) FROM CartItemEvents cie INNER JOIN CartItems ci on o.CartId=ci.CartId WHERE cie.CartItemId=ci.Id 
                                    AND   cie.EventDate=
                                    (SELECT MAX(EventDate) FROM CartItemEvents WHERE ci.id=CartItemId)) 
   AS 'status'
FROM Orders o
```

Did it. I removed the Left Join at the end and instead made an Inner Join in the subquery.